# plt.plot categorical axis overcrowded

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently plotting a data frame which consists of 119 observations that represent recycling rates (float) by country (categorical). I've tried to make a scatter plot and a bar plot, but both times encountered overcrowding of the categorical y-axis.

I thought it was possible to make the axis bigger or increase space between categories, but didn't manage to find anything helpful. Could you explain to me how to improve code so that all countries on the y-axis are observable?

Attached is MWE (though it is ultimately simple), the `plt.plot()` output, and `dataset.info()`.

MWE:

```
plt.plot(
    rr_data['r_rate'], 
    rr_data['country'], 
    '.', 
    color='red')
plt.title('Recycling rates by country')
plt.ylabel('Countrycode')
plt.xlabel('Waste recycled, %')
```

Info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 119 entries, 0 to 120
Data columns (total 2 columns):
country    119 non-null object
r_rate     119 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 2.8+ KB
```

Plot:
[rr_by_country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMbD6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the size of the whole figure using `figsize=(x,y)`

So you could simply

```
plt.plot(rr_data['r_rate'], rr_data['country'], figsize(20,20),'.',color='red')
plt.title('Recycling rates by country')
plt.ylabel('Countrycode')
plt.xlabel('Waste recycled, %')
```

Is that what you were looking for? You can play around with the numbers to increase the plot in the desired way

Comment: It actually is. Didn't think it is that simple, thanks a lot.

However, you need to set the figure size before you plot as follows: 
```plt.figure(figsize=(x,y))```. 

Otherwise, it yields a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can define the size of the figure. For example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplot(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.plot(rr_data['r_rate'], rr_data['country'], figsize(10,10),'.',color='red')
```

OR

```
plt.plot(rr_data['r_rate'], rr_data['country'], figsize(10,10),'.',color='red')
```

OR

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(...)

fig.set_size_inches(width,height)
```